# Get data from SQLite database and put it in a table

Tags: android, sqlite, row

I am trying to get data from sqlite database and put it in a table, it works but the problem is the data from the database are disordered like this:

[image]

and I want the data to be ordered and to be in rows like this:

[image]

my xml file

```
    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

             <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/textView1" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Id"
              android:layout_weight="1" >
            </TextView>


             <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/textView2" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Name"
              android:layout_weight="1" >
            </TextView>


             <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/textView3" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="Email"
              android:layout_weight="1" >
            </TextView>

        </TextView>



</TableLayout>
<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSQLinfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="get the info from database"
             />
        </TableRow>
```

my java file

```
public String getData() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL};
Cursor c = ourDbase.query(TABLE_USER, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
String result ="";

int aRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
int aName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
int aEmail = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL);


for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
result =  result + c.getString(aRow) +  c.getString(aName)  + c.getString(aEmail) + "\n"; 
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: you have to make proper format of inflater layout for this.

Comment: You need a ListView instead of a TableLayout